# Give an example of subset $B$ of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ so the subsets $A$, $Int(A)$, $\overline{A}$, dont intersect

Tags: general-topology

What is an example of a subset $A$ of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ (equipped with the standard metric topology), such that
the subsets $A$, $Int(A)$, $\overline{A}$, $\overline{Int(A)}$ and Int($\overline{A}$) are pairwise different?

Comment: Welcome to mathSE. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please add some information about your work done. As is the question will be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $B=\Bbb Q\cap(1,2),$ and let $A=(0,1)\cup B.$

Comment: ok, we got the same idea ahah (Typing latex with a phone is harder though)

Comment: True! Hence my brevity. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take $A=((0,1) \cap \mathbb{Q}) \cup (2,3)$. The interior of A is $(2,3)$, the closure of A is $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$, the closure of the interior of A is $[2,3]$, and the interior of the closure of A is $(0,1) \cup (2,3)$.